# El DrawerLayout no se muestra al usar el componente Navigation y MenuProvider en los fragmentos hijos

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Tengo una app que usa componente Navigation, y hay algunos fragmentos del grafo de navegación que necesitan inflar sus propios menús. Todo bien hasta aquí pero cuando intento usar MenuProvider con MenuHost para evitar usar onOptionsItemSelected y onCreateOptionsMenu pues están deprecados se vuelve imposible abrir el menú de hamburguesa

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_content"
        android:id="@+id/content" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main_content.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navController"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

En mi MainActivity tengo definido mi navController así:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)
        toolbar = binding!!.appBar.toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        drawerLayout = binding!!.drawerLayout
        navView = binding!!.navView
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navController)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.home,
                R.id.otherSection
            ),
            drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    // Aquí inflo otras opciones del menú que corresponden a acciones globales fuera del DrawerLayout
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.other_options_non_in_drawer, menu)
        return true
                            }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else if (searchBox.isIconified.not()) {
            searchBox.isIconified = true
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Y en mis fragmentos tengo algo como esto para inflar los menús:

```kotlin
class OtherSection : Fragment(), MenuProvider {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as MenuHost).addMenuProvider(
            this,
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.other_section_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Aquí manejo mis menús y lo que harán
    }
}
```

Entonces al momento de ejecutar la app los menús definidos en el activity como en el fragment se inflan y se manejan correctamente pero al presionar el menú de hamburguesa nada pasa. Ya intenté extender MenuProvider y hacer addMenuProvider en mi activity moviendo toda la lógica de los menús a los métodos de la interfaz de MenuProvider pero sigue sin poder abrirse el menú de hamburguesa

Pero cuando uso los métodos deprecados de onOptionsItemSelected y onCreateOptionsMenu en mis fragmentos si funciona, alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logré resolver esto, al final así quedaría el código:

````kotlin
// Extendemos la interfaz MenuProvider en la clase
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)
        toolbar = binding!!.appBar.toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        // Agregamos la activity como manejador del menu provider
        addMenuProvider(this)

        drawerLayout = binding!!.drawerLayout
        navView = binding!!.navView
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navController)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.home,
                R.id.otherSection
            ),
            drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    // Sustituyo el onCreateOptionsMenu deprecado por el método de la interfaz
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.other_options_non_in_drawer, menu)
                            }

    /*
     * Agrego el menu item selected listener,
     * ahora aquí debo lanzar el manejador del menú hamburguesa del navController
    */
    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean = when (menuItem.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
        else -> true
    }

    // Esto supongo que ya no es necesario
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else if (searchBox.isIconified.not()) {
            searchBox.isIconified = true
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}```
````